# level indicator using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can we add class at each level like below using Jquery/JS? So that we can identify that on which level of list we are..

```
<ul>
<li class="level1">level 1
     <ul>
     <li class="level2">level 2</li>
     <li class="level2">level 2</li>
     <li class="level2">level 2
         <ul>
         <li class="level3">level 3</li>
         <li class="level3">level 3</li>
         <li class="level3">level 3
             <ul>
             <li class="level4">level 4</li>
             <li class="level4">level 4</li>
             <li class="level4">level 4</li>
             </ul>
         </li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     <ul>
</li>
<li class="level1">level 1</li>
<li class="level1">level 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing? This above code is valid

Comment: What is the reason you need to do this with jQuery and not just markup? Are they dynamically added elements?

Comment: You can do this with CSS using `>` - did you need jquery?  (as you can do it in css, you *can* do it in jquery, but checking what you need vs what you think you want...)

Comment: actually want to add dynamic classes like above given code on each level..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try utilizing `.each()` , `.parents()` , `.length`

```js
$("li").each(function(i,el) {
  $(this).addClass("level" + $(this).parents("ul").length)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul>
<li>level 1
     <ul>
     <li>level 2</li>
     <li>level 2</li>
     <li>level 2
         <ul>
         <li>level 3</li>
         <li>level 3</li>
         <li>level 3
             <ul>
             <li>level 4</li>
             <li>level 4</li>
             <li>level 4</li>
             </ul>
         </li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     </ul>

</li>
<li>level 1</li>
<li>level 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But all the parents look ups might be slow.  Only downside to that

Answer (score 2):

This is a way without needing to keep looking up the parents.

```js
(function find(par, index) {
    index += 1; 
    var lis = par.find("> li").addClass("level" + index);
    if (lis.length) {
        find(lis.find("> ul"),index);  
    }
}($("ul#start"),0))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul id="start">
<li>level 1
     <ul>
     <li>level 2</li>
     <li>level 2</li>
     <li>level 2
         <ul>
         <li>level 3</li>
         <li>level 3</li>
         <li>level 3
             <ul>
             <li>level 4</li>
             <li>level 4</li>
             <li>level 4</li>
             </ul>
         </li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     </ul>

</li>
<li>level 1</li>
<li>level 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Huh, I would have expected yours to be about the equivalent of mine, but the jsperf shows a significant difference.  My guess is my default parameter checks are really slowing it down.

Comment: The `> li` I am sure is expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple recursive function.

```js
function addLevels(parent, level) {
  parent = parent || $("body").children("ul");
  level = level || 1;
  var children = parent.children("li");
  children.addClass("level" + level);
  parent = children.children("ul");
  if (parent.length)
    addLevels(parent, ++level);
}

$(function() {
  addLevels();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>level 1
    <ul>
      <li>level 2</li>
      <li>level 2</li>
      <li>level 2
        <ul>
          <li>level 3</li>
          <li>level 3</li>
          <li>level 3
            <ul>
              <li>level 4</li>
              <li>level 4</li>
              <li>level 4</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>level 1</li>
  <li>level 1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want some extra speed you can try a pure javascript solution. Here is a JsFiddle for some food for thought.

http://jsfiddle.net/fqp74r8j/

```
var listArr = document.querySelectorAll('ul');

[].forEach.call(listArr, function(el, i) {
    var listLen = el.children.length;

    for (var j = 0; j < el.children.length; j++) {
        el.children[j].classList.add('level-' + (i + 1));
    }
});
```